# How to get Visual Studio to generate the override stub for an event declared in a base type?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to override an event handler in a subclass - how can i get VS2008 to generate the stub?

For that matter can it generate the code for a method override?

Is there a trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, but did you tried [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/)  from Devexprees, it may have this facility.